MongoDB - Find matches where part of path is dynamic
I have data structured as follows:
{
    "_id": "1234",
    "Nodes": {
        "-14": {
            "_t": "DL",
            "Key": "-14",
            "Edges": [
                {
                    "TargetNode": "-5"
                }
            ],
            "Title": "Lookup",
            "Text": "Data Lookup",
            "ConnectionString": "Server=LOCALSERVER;Database=DataCache;User=sa;Password=1234;",
            "TableName": "Customers",
            "FieldMaps": [
                {
                    "ID": 2,
                    "Column": "Name"
                },
                {
                    "ID": 1,
                    "Column": "Number"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Ultimately I am trying to replace the 'Server=LOCALSERVER' with 'Server=NEWSERVER' (using updateMany). However, I am stuck trying to determine how to find all matches in the collection. My issue is that the node ID (i.e. "-14") under "Nodes" may change depending on the "_id".
When I use this:
db.getCollection('workflows').find({"Nodes.-14.ConnectionString": {$regex: /^Server=LOCALSERVER/}})

it returns the matches where the node ID equals -14. However, as stated above, the node ID can change based on the _id.
I don't have a lot of experience working in MongoDB, and am trying to find the best way to capture all potential matches of the changing node ID (node ID is a negative numeric value). I have tried this:
db.getCollection('workflows').find({"Nodes.{$regex: '-\d{1,}'}.ConnectionString": {$regex: /^Server=LOCALSERVER/}})

but MongoDB does not seem to support using RegEx in naming the dynamic key. I did read a little about objectToArray and elemMatch commands in MongoDB, but I'm not sure if either would find the various node IDs.
Is there another command that does this, and is there an example code based on what I have described? If there is another post that supports this, please let me know and I can try to user that to build my query. Thank you for taking a look.

This is the reason why using dynamic values for field names is considered an anti-pattern. You will need an unnecessarily complex query to achieve what you need.
Consider a simple refactor by breaking the Nodes object into 2 fields, NodesKey and NodesValue like below:
[
  {
    "_id": "1234",
    "NodesKey": "-14",
    "NodesValue": {
      "_t": "DL",
      "Key": "-14",
      "Edges": [
        {
          "TargetNode": "-5"
        }
      ],
      "Title": "Lookup",
      "Text": "Data Lookup",
      "ConnectionString": "Server=LOCALSERVER;Database=DataCache;User=sa;Password=1234;",
      "TableName": "Customers",
      "FieldMaps": [
        {
          "ID": 2,
          "Column": "Name"
        },
        {
          "ID": 1,
          "Column": "Number"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

You can perform a rather simple query like this:
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "NodesValue.ConnectionString": {
        "$replaceOne": {
          "input": "$NodesValue.ConnectionString",
          "find": "Server=LOCALSERVER",
          "replacement": "Server=NEWSERVER"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

For your current scenario, you will need to use $objectToArray to wrangle Nodes object into an array of k-v tuples. Then use $map to iterate through the array elements and use $mergeObjects to update the value. This is going to be complex as you are nesting the structures.
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "Nodes": {
        "$objectToArray": "$Nodes"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "Nodes": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Nodes",
          "as": "n",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$n",
              {
                "v": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$n.v",
                    {
                      "ConnectionString": {
                        "$replaceOne": {
                          "input": "$$n.v.ConnectionString",
                          "find": "Server=LOCALSERVER",
                          "replacement": "Server=NEWSERVER"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "Nodes": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$Nodes"
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Thank you for your quick reply @ray! My apologies for not responding sooner. Your solution absolutely worked. I appreciate your suggestion on how the data could be restructured to more easily update these going forward. The only thing I changed on my end was using $replaceAll instead of $replaceOne, since each record may sometimes include multiple instances of the string being replaced. I am including that in case it helps others on a similar issue in the future. Thanks again!
